# How to check input field just in case value was changed in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some input fields and I want to call function only to input fields, which was changed. I have read a Documentation about **onChanges**, but still have not idea...So let's say I have a function, and if I press button, it adds 5 to counter, if word was changed.

```
 @ViewChild('f') array_of_words: any;

check(){
 for (let i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
if ((this.array_of_words.value[i] === value[i] was changed)
this.score = this.score+5;
}
```

I know, code doesn't now, but it is just example to get an idea...
What could I write instead of `value[i] was changed`? Please, help me, I just begin to learn Angular 2 and would be thankful for any help from you:)

PS. I have this code also

```
  onValueChange(this.array_of_words: any, i: any) {
    this.valueChanged.emit(this.array_of_words.value[i]);
  }
```

Maybe I could use it somehow?...

My child component is

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, Output, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fill-in-blank',
  template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let text of texts; let i = index">
      {{text}}<input *ngIf="i!==texts.length-1" type="text" name="{{i}}" ngModel  [id]="i" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(f,i)">

    </ng-container>
    </form>
    <pre>{{f.value | json}}</pre>
    <button (click)="check()">Give me object</button>
    <p>Score {{score}}</p>
    <button (click)="check2()">Give me object2</button>
  `
})
export class FillInBlankComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('f') f: any;

  @Input() textline: string;

  @Input() fields: string[];

  @Output() valueChanged = new EventEmitter();



  texts: string[];

  value: string[] = [];

  score: number = 0;
  count: number = 0;
  a:number;

  constructor() {
  }




  ngOnInit() {

    let regex = null;
    if (this.fields && this.fields.length > 0) {
      regex = new RegExp(this.fields.join("|"), 'gi');
    }

    this.texts = this.textline.split(regex);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {

    if (changes['f'] && this.f) {

      //your logic work when input change
      alert("a");
    }}

  onValueChange(f: any, i: any) {
    this.valueChanged.emit(f.value[i]);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }
  /*ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    console.log(changes[this.f].currentValue);
  } */

  check() {
    if(this.count === 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
        if (this.f.value[i] === this.fields[i]) {
          alert("OK");
          this.score += 50;

        } else {
          alert("Wrong");
        }
      }
    }
    return this.count = 1;
  }

  check2() {
    if (this.count === 1 ) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
        if ((this.f.value[i] === this.fields[i]) ) {
          alert("OK");
          this.score += 25;

        } else {
          alert("Wrong");
        }
      }
    }



  }
}
```

My parent component is

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <fill-in-blank [textline]="itemsSource" [fields]="abc" (valueChanged)="printValue($event)"></fill-in-blank>
    <p>{{values}}</p>
    <p>{{itemsSource}}</p>
    <p>{{abc}}</p>

`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public itemsSource: string;
  public abc: string[];
  public values: string[];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.abc = ['orange', 'blue'];
    this.itemsSource = 'I like orange, blue, black, pink, rose, yellow, white, black';

  }
  printValue($event: any) {


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are discussing input fields the topic you want to read about is forms. Angular has very good built-in behaviors that will automatically notice changes in form input.

Check template driven forms:
https://angular.io/guide/forms

Especially this subsection:
https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this, but the problem is that I want to type in my inputs fields something, than call a function, which adds 10 to score(here is no problem), and then I want second try and second function - in this case just 5. So, the inputs are yet "touched, so I guess in my case it wont work?..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `(change)` property to execute a function when the input changes.

`<input (change)="check($event)" name="arrayofwords">`

```
class Component {
    arrayofwordscount = 0;
    check(event) {
        if(event.srcElement.name == 'arrayofwords') {
            this.arrayofwordscount++;
        }
        if (this.arrayofwordscount == 5) {
            this.score += 5; // or whatever else you want it to do when it has been edited 5 times
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you! in my case i need to access $event from parent component, how could I do this?

Comment: Put the change detector on the parent component, and use an `@Output()` on your child component, or you can use a `@HostListener()`

Comment: @HostListener OK, so my change detector in parent component is    `printValue($event: any) {}` so what could I write inside curly brackets in this function to use it later? set some value to boolean? Sorry for that question, I   am beginner:)

Comment: @Natali So what you would do is you would put an [`@Output listener: EventEmitter`](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/) on your child component. Then, on the child component, you would have a method `printValueChild($event) {this.listener.emit($event)}`. On the component selector inside of the parent component, you would put `(listener)="printValue($event)"`. Et voila!